# reportWebVitals missing return type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Out of the box `npx create-react-app app-name --template typescript` produces the following:

[image]

I couldn't seem to find anywhere on what the expected return type is for this. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It doesn't return anything right? Then assign return type to be void as linter suggests

Comment: Look at the implementation - use the _actual_ return type.

Comment: Thanks, I guess sometimes I just need a 2nd set of eyes. I'll leave this question up in case anyone else googles this, as I think this should have been added as out of the box template...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just assign return type to be void as linter suggests:

```
const reportWebVitals = (onPerfEntry: ReportHandler): void => ...
```